# How can I make a maven plugin to notify build results?

Tags: maven-3

I develop a simple plugin to notify build results to desktop like growl.
https://github.com/kompiro/notification-maven-plugin

Now, I think there are no good way to listen build result event.

I tested two way to listen the event.

a. ExecutionListener from MavenSession#getRequest()

This way is implemented below.
https://github.com/kompiro/notification-maven-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/kompiro/nortification/buildresult/NotificationMojo.java

This way is running well to notify, but there is a problem. It replaced default maven event execution listener.
So, if user add this plugin, there are no maven execution log. 
I thought my implementation extends the default event execution listener "ExecutionEventLogger",
But I can't because The constructor of ExecutionEventLogger needs plexus's logger.
I can't get the logger object.

b. use EventSpy

This is not public interface and user must add the plugin to maven.ext classpath.It is not good for user.

How can I listen the event correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just setup a Jenkins server on your local desktop and have it run the tests and notify you?

There is probably a growl-like notifier for Jenkins somewhere, or worst case just get it to sent an email to localhost with the test results. This also has the advantage of keeping historical test results.

If you are using a nice SCM such as GIT then you can set Jenkins up to poll your local checkout as its upstream, so that you check all your commits individually. If using a less good SCM, I would just have the first step of the job copy all the sources from your workspace into Jenkins' workspace so that you can continue to code away without fear of breaking Jenkins' compile phases.

Also I would favour a FreeStyle project with Maven build step to the built in Maven project type (but then that might just be my own personal bias)

Comment: This idea is really interesting. But my machine doesn't have so much spec.

Comment: Don't need that much spec to run Jenkins... and if you have enough spec to be doing other things while the tests are running, you probably have enough spec to run a single Jenkins instance